# migrating custom_rules.xml (Eclipse, Ant) to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My custom_rules.xml file has a custom target, let's say my-target.  Target -pre-build depends on my-target.  my-target generates a property file and places it into assets directory.

I am migrating my project from Eclipse to Android Studio and would like to keep this functionality.  It seems that the generated files should be placed to  MyAppProject/MyApp/build/assets/[debug|release] folders.  What would be the best Gradle task to use for this purpose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation it looks like the best Gradle tasks for this purpose are mergeDebugAssets and mergeReleaseAssets:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    mergeDebugAssets {
        doLast {
            generateAssets(outputDir, false)
        }
    }
    mergeReleaseAssets {
        doLast {
            generateAssets(outputDir, true)
        }
    }
}
```

where generateAssets(File, boolean) is my method that generates required asset files